# How to get Chrome://media-internals logs in javascript code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video

I want to get chrome log in my program because even if I attached `onerror` in  `video` tag but large ts gap error can't be fired, only if I open `media-internals` tag and can see it like this:

[image]

I want to collect these error messages through my js code, please help.